# Error installing nio4r 2.1.0 and bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install and try a new project on rails but I can't even create a new project for this error.
the mkmf.log file shows:

```
"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

please help...